# Creating upload multiple document functionality using thymeleaf back-end is Java

Tags: jquery, file-upload, upload, thymeleaf

I All,

I need help in creating upload functionality using thymeleaf in which need to create upload button having add more button.

box + upload button + add more functionality by clicking on add more another box should come up having same functionality of add file which will be purely dynamic.

I m new to thymeleaf it will be great help if any person can be my mentor on this task and guide me step by step. Backend i can write using Java i just need help on front end.

Thanks and Regards in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div>
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
                <table>
                    <tr><td>File to upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file"      /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>

                </table>
            </form>
   </div>
```

This will have you work done and you can  map "addMore " to the java code . This can be additional help to you where you can list all the documents uploaded.

```
<div>
        <ul>
            <li th:each="file : ${files}">
                <a th:href="${file}" th:text="${file}" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: If i need 3 files to be uploaded do i need to do it static like name="haFiles[0].uploadFile" or i can use it dynamically?